# Deprovision device using Azure Device Provisioning Service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-dps

I'm trying to understand Azure Device Provisioning Service. I provision my virtual device using X.509 certificate and send messages in IoThub.

Now,I tried to temporary disable my device as mention in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/how-to-unprovision-devices#individual-enrollments) but I don't see any impact in IoThub side. I can see device status is disabled in DPS but enabled in IoThub.

Last I removed my device from DPS but still I can see device in IoThub.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you're seeing is correct. The Device Provisioning Service will assign your device to an IoT Hub, but will not remove it once you delete the enrollment. The process of deprovisioning a device is [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-dps/how-to-unprovision-devices?view=aps-pdw-2016).

Comment: you are correct. but I'm wondering why MS added manual deregistration process? why not auto deregistration.

Comment: I agree it would be a convenient option. But in many cases, removing a device enrollment doesn't mean the device should be blocked from the IoT Hub. There are cases where a device only needs the DPS once.